# IK-rig doesn't bend when I add elbow-target/elbow-pole

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I have an IK-rig set up for my arm. An upper arm bone, a lower arm bone and the arm-IK bone, like so(front-view):

[image]

The IK-rig works until I add an elbow target/elbow pole. At this point, the arm stops bending.

It goes from bending beautifully like this(top-view):
[image]

To not bending, no matter where the IK-bone is placed(top-view):
[image]

How do I make the arm bend when I have an elbow-target/elbow-pole?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Seems like what's needed is a tiny bend in the armature, in edit mode. In other words, Blender needs to know where your elbow is bending towards. Go into edit mode, move the connection between the upper arm and lower arm just a little bit towards the elbow target/elbow pole. Then you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be because it's ambiguous which way the elbow should bend when you move the target in exactly on line with the arm. Try adding a pole target to your IK solver constraint. This will tell the elbow which way to point, making it unambiguous. I'm not sure about this myself, but it's probably worth a try.